# Link in Fixed Div is not clickable?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a top-bar like so:

```
<div class="lesson_title">
    <a class="backButton" href="/courses/1">Back</a>
    <h2 class="lesson_name">Lesson 5</h2>
</div>
```

For some reason, that .backButton link is NOT clickable.

Here's a gist with the ERB, compiled HTML and CSS:

https://gist.github.com/justuseapen/8800dff9147ebf4442e2

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

To break it down further, there are a couple divs at play here. A wrapper called .current_lesson and an adjacent div called .player.

To me, it appears that .player or .lesson_name are covered the link_to "back" but I've played with the z-indexes to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears as it the `lesson_name` is sitting above the `backButton` in the z-index. So what you are clicking on is the `lesson_name` `h2` and not the `backButton`

For stuff like this its better to put it in a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've tried setting the z-indexes but haven't had any luck :/